# Difference between done() vs spread() of bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, q, bluebird

Hi I am not getting what is the difference of `spread()`  vs `done()` of bluebird library of JavaScript.Even bluebird is wrapper of `Q` so Q also has both the functions in it's library.

Can anybody explain me what is the difference between both of these functions?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Even bluebird is wrapper of Q so…

Oh, definitely not. I hope this doesn't invalidate your question?

> I am not getting what is the difference of `spread()` vs `done()`?

The API docs might help a lot:

- [`spread`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) is "*like calling `.then`, but the fulfillment value or rejection reason must be an array, which is flattened to the formal parameters of the handlers.*"

  If you have a promise for an array, `spread` will call your callbacks with **multiple arguments**.

  It's just the same what Q does: [`spread`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisespreadonfulfilled-onrejected) is "*Like `then`, but "spreads" the array into a variadic fulfillment handler.*"
- [`done`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#donefunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----void) is "*like `.then()`, but any **unhandled rejection** that ends up here will be thrown as an error. [… It] is used to explicitly mark the end of a promise chain.*"

  More details on this can be found in the [error handling](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#error-handling) documentation. Notice that bluebird is quite different from Q here, as it smartly figures out unhandled rejection and [reports them on its own](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#error-management-configuration) - you don't have to explicitly tell it to throw a global error when a rejection got to some point.

  Compare that to [Q's `done` documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress), which recommends its unconfined use.

As you can see, `spread` and `done` are completely different methods with different purposes. Also, the `done` patterns differ between Bluebird and Q.